# Unix awk, flag function, multiple if condition

Tags: awk

I have a large document and I am working within two patterns with the flag command:

```
/Nodes/ {f=1} /EndNodes/ {f=0}
```

I get the desired output and now I have to filter this to get 20, 31 and 32 as an output. I am using this command:

```
{if ($2 + 0 >= 0 && $3 + 0 == 0 && max = $4)
{print $1}}
```

But I get this result:

> 20,31,32,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34.

Notice that the numbers from 18 to 34 fulfill the `max = $4` condition. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As steeldriver pointed out, a single `=` is an assignment operation, which results a value -- the one that you're assigning. If that value is positive (as the numbers 18 through 34 are), then the assignment *value* is positive, which is "true" in awk.

Simply change `max = $4` to `max == $4` to make it a comparison test instead of an assignment.